# GNU nano 2.2.6 won't show ₹ (rupees sign)

Tags: unicode, nano

I have a file which contain ₹ (rupees) sign.

[image]

but with `nano`

[image]

**Update: Is there something wrong with my locale?**

```
:~$ cat /etc/default/locale
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_GB:en"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

---

I don't think that colour profile of my terminal is making it invisible because I tried different types of profile to make sure...

Comment: I can confirm the same behavior in 2.4.2. Definitely a bug in nano. Could you please file them a bugreport?

Comment: @egmont yes, but how?

Comment: The manpage says write a mail to nano@nano-editor.org; the homepage has a Contact page which points you to Savannah's bugtracker. Not sure which one is the better.

Comment: If this comes through your Linux (or other) distribution, report it there. It might be a "local" mistake, if not, they are in better position to report it upstream.

Comment: If it's a bug it might have been fixed already. I use 2.4.2 and there it are shown.

Comment: @AlMehdi how do I update my nano ?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I am on Arch... not sure if it is possible on Ubuntu. If so probably through a PPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [v2.4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236948/gnu-nano-2-2-6-wont-show-%E2%82%B9-rupees-sign/248946#comment405532_236948) (obviously, v2.2 too) has either bug or cannot display some of the unicode characters. v2.5 can display rupee sign